# Sci-fi/horror movie involving soldiers being pulled inside a tanker

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I am trying to identify a horror movie that really shocked me when I was a kid 10-15 years ago, based on one scene that’s stuck in my head over the years. Some more info:

- I believe it was a horror movie involving ghosts or other supernatural creatures.
- Possibly one of those low budget SyFy channel originals, since we had that playing often.
- Aired on TV in the late 2000’s or early 2010’s.
- The notable scene was of some soldiers in modern military gear escorting a tanker truck or similar through a foggy area. There’s a ghost or some other supernatural creature in the tanker. At some point it breaks free and begins telekinetically pulling the soldiers into the tanker through the opening on top. The reason this scene stuck in my head was how violent this scene was, with the screaming and bone snapping as they were forced through the small opening.

I don’t remember too much else about the movie beyond this scene. Google searches for some of the descriptions above didn’t turn up much. I’d like to see if this scene is as scary now as it was to me back then.

Comment: If not for the timing, I feel like 2021's *Army of the Dead* is a good match/